# Convex signal reconstruction for convex generator function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a convex (not affine) function and suppose that $y = f(x)$. We want to reconstruct the input $x$ for a given $y$, and the standard approach would be to minimize

$$L(x) = (y - f(x))^2 = y^2 + f(x)^2 - 2yf(x).$$

In general $L$ will not be convex: for $y > 0$ and $f$ nonnegative the second term is convex and the last term is concave.

**Is there any way to formulate such a reconstruction problem in a convex way?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem can have multiple minima (e.g $f(x)=x^2$ with $y>0$) so it can't possibly be formulated as a convex optimization unless you find a way to eliminate one of the minima.

Comment: Sure. The case $f(x) = x^2$ could be easily resolved by restricting $x$ to the nonnegative real space. However, other cases are less easy to handle, e.g. $f(x) = [x]_+$.

Comment: Unless you are willing to guarantee (or constrain) that $f(x) \geq y$, then no.

Comment: But this is univariate. Why worry so much about convexity? Global optimization (i.e., intelligent exhaustive search) is straightforward in a situation like this.

Comment: @Michael Grant: I agree - this of course just a toy problem. In the end I am much more interested in very high-dimensional problems (for which the problem gets, of course, even more difficult). Are there at least some special convex functions for which the reconstruction problem is convex?

Comment: Generally, the anwser is **No**. I would use and affine $f$ (hence, linear regression), and then use a "kernel trick" (google it) to inject any non-linearity prior afterwards.